How to use WordPress inner blocks in html templates?
I'm trying to use a block that has nested inner blocks in the front-page.html template.
Is there any way to do this?
I have one wrapper block and one content block, which changes based on the template.
The wrapper block supports InnerBlocks;
I want to set up front-page.html which is the default homepage template for WordPress to user the wrapper block with the content block as its innerblocks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
